# Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, java-8, garbage-collection

I'm running a Spring boot app locally in my windows system with 5GB of RAM. I was hitting one of the three POST API of the application. It takes queryString as parameter in requestBody and fetches data from postgres DB. OutofMemory was expected as the dataSize is huge but what is

> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor run
>   SEVERE: Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
>   WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=51352] throws
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

After these Error application becomes unresponsive. I was also analyzing heap usage in VisualVM, GC was immediately clearing the heap memory once these errors are thrown (please refer attached screenshot) but why heap size didn't reach 5GB before throwing out of memory?
What might be the reason for the above errors and possible fix for them?

```
Exception in thread "http-nio-80-ClientPoller-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.timeout(NioEndpoint.java:1013)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:833)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 27, 2020 11:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor run
SEVERE: Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.backgroundProcess(Cache.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.backgroundProcess(StandardRoot.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5582)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1360)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.backgroundProcess(Cache.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.backgroundProcess(StandardRoot.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5582)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1360)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 27, 2020 11:31:13 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=51352] throws
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
        at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(Unknown Source)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 27, 2020 11:31:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Mayank, do you have and news here?